# Why isn't NPM including files when published?

Tags: javascript, file, npm, include, package

I have a small package which sets up a default project for me. It copies a set of static files and a set of templates which it populates with strings from a config file. When I publish the package, npm includes all but two of the files in the project. The two files are:

- `/templates/package.json`
- `/templates/rollup.config.js`

I have no `.npmignore` and both files are checked into git (and don't appear in my `.gitignore`). I do not use the `files` field in my `package.json`. I wondered if the file names were the problem but neither of these file names appear in npm's [default list](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) of excluded files.

**Why is NPM excluding these files?**

You can see the repo [here](https://github.com/Undistraction/default-template) and the package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@undistraction/default-template).

Comment: I would love to collaborate on this project if you're cool with that.

Comment: It's really a personal project - that's why I namespaced the package. It's exactly what I need which will not be what the next person needs. There are other way more generic and complex things like Yeoman that already do this well but are too complex for my needs. If you find it useful just fork it and customise it. If you think you've added something useful then by all means submit a PR, but I'm not looking to abstract anything.

Comment: ummm, is it okay if I contact (email or DM or any other means you're comfortable with) you privately outside SO?